# list of short text, want to choose lines that are at least 2 letters different

Tags: r, awk

I have a list of 8 letter DNA sequences, for example:

```
    GGAGACAA  
    GGATACAA 
    AATCAGTC 
    ACACCTGG
```

I want to select all of the lines that are **positionally** at least 2 letters different than every other line. Ideally I'd want to keep lines 3,4 and 1 OR 2 (but don't care which). But at a minimum, I want to keep 3 and 4. Most important is that there are no lines included that have only one positional base difference from any other retained line.

How would you do it? R, grep/gawk are my usual tools but I can't figure out how to do what seems like a simple task using those.

ETA-lines one and two are only one letter different from each other (G vs T in the fourth position). Which is why I don't want to retain both of them.  There are ~65,000 possible combinations of 8 bases so most of my (~4000 line) list should meet this 2 letters different from all other lines criteria.  I'm having a hard time figure out how to find those few that don't.

Comment: What do you mean by "2 letters different?"  Do you mean two strands which differ by exactly 2 base pairs?

Comment: In your example above, which lines are at least 2 letters different from "any other line"? I see no two lines that differ by at most one letter, so surely they are all at least 2 letters different from any other line? Can you give an example of a word that is *not* at least 2 letters different from any (do you mean every?) other line?

Comment: I changed my example to try to make what I want clearer

Comment: Line 1 contains the letters A, C, and G. All of the other lines contain A, C, G, and T which makes them 1 letter different from line 1. You will need to edit your question to explain to us in what way any of those lines is "2 letters different" from any other.

Comment: AH, I see the problem. Position matters,  there are only 4 possible letters but which letter is in each position is retained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `adist`:

```
txt <- c("GGAGACAA", "GGATACAA", "AATCAGTC", "ACACCTGG")
d <- adist(txt)
diag(d) <- Inf
cuts <- col(d)[lower.tri(d)][d[lower.tri(d)] <= 2]
#[1] 1  # will be removed:
txt[-cuts]
#[1] "GGATACAA" "AATCAGTC" "ACACCTGG"
```

Comment: Very nice! didn't know about `adist`

I noticed the distance output is different from mine for "GGATACAA" vs "AATCAGTC" - 7 for mine, 6 with `adist`. I'm guessing it's because edit distance can achieve a shorter route to make the two similar using inserts (e.g. when two letters are already in the right order but out of position) rather than pure substitutions (which is my approach) ?

Answer (score 6):

The [stringdist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/index.html) package has function stringdistmatrix and many different distance metrics.

```
> library(stringdist)
> stringdistmatrix(x, x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    7    7
[2,]    1    0    6    7
[3,]    7    6    0    5
[4,]    7    7    5    0
```

It's now up to you to figure out what you mean by "2 letters different"!

Comment: `adist(x)` gives the same result.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about `stringdistmatrix`.

I'm guessing what the OP is looking for is `stringdistmatrix(x, x, "hamming")`, which should produce same output as my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Replicating the data

```
txt <- c("GGAGACAA", "GGATACAA", "AATCAGTC", "ACACCTGG")
```

Comparing all sequences

```
# split into letters
txtw <- sapply(txt, strsplit, "")
# find differences
txtc <- lapply(txtw, function(x) sapply(txtw, function(y) sum(x!=y)))
```

The output is a list of how many letters in the same place is different compared to other letter sequences

```
> txtc
$GGAGACAA
GGAGACAA GGATACAA AATCAGTC ACACCTGG 
       0        1        7        7 

$GGATACAA
GGAGACAA GGATACAA AATCAGTC ACACCTGG 
       1        0        7        7 

$AATCAGTC
GGAGACAA GGATACAA AATCAGTC ACACCTGG 
       7        7        0        6 

$ACACCTGG
GGAGACAA GGATACAA AATCAGTC ACACCTGG 
       7        7        6        0
```

If your comparison is for "GGAGACAA", 2 meets your criterion

```
> txtc[["GGAGACAA"]] > 1
GGAGACAA GGATACAA AATCAGTC ACACCTGG 
   FALSE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
```

But if your reference is e.g. "AATCAGTC", all (except "AATCAGTC" itself) meets your criterion

```
> txtc[["AATCAGTC"]] > 1
GGAGACAA GGATACAA AATCAGTC ACACCTGG 
    TRUE     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE
```

So I guess you need to decide which one is the reference. If you summarise the difference against all others, I guess for another dataset you may find something which is different from everything else (i.e. shows as 3 below), but your sample shows all of them have at least 2 other strings which have at least 2 letters different.

```
> sapply(txtc, function(x) sum(x>1))
GGAGACAA GGATACAA AATCAGTC ACACCTGG 
       2        2        3        3
```

**EDIT:** following the above approach, to identify the sequence which is at least different in 2 spaces from everything else is simply finding those with non-zero output for the last line. However the given sample data doesn't seem to have anything fulfilling that criterion, so I will re-run with a different data set below:

```
txt <- c("GGAGACAA", "GGATACAA", "GGACACAA", "AGATACAA")
txtw <- sapply(txt, strsplit, "")
txtc <- lapply(txtw, function(x) sapply(txtw, function(y) sum(x!=y)))
# counting the number of different sequence against all sequences
matches <- sapply(txtc, function(x) sum(x>1))
# find those which has at least 1 other different sequence
different <- matches[matches>0]
```

In the example above, "GGATACAA" is only one character different from everything else, so I expect the output to exclude it,

```
> different
GGAGACAA GGACACAA AGATACAA 
       1        1        2
```

which is the case. The numbers above are the number of sequences with at least 2 letter difference. "GGAGACAA" and "GGACACAA" are only 1-letter different from each other, but are retained because they have 1 other sequence that fulfills that criterion i.e. "AGATACAA". "AGATACAA" has 2 other sequences that fulfill the criterion.

Comment: I feel like this is getting on the correct track.  But I can't have a single reference, I want to retain all that have at least 2 bases different from any other retained sequence

Comment: I have edited my answer. I think my approach works, but (if I understand you correctly) your sample data set doesn't have any were there is a sequence which does not fulfill your criterion (at least 2 bases different), so I've given an example with a different data set, see if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ a[NR] = $0 }
END {
    lgth = length(a[1])
    for (i=1;i<=NR;i++) {
        maxSame = 0

        for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                numSame = 0
                for (k=1;k<=lgth;k++) {
                    if ( substr(a[i],k,1) == substr(a[j],k,1) ) {
                        numSame++
                    }
                }
                maxSame = (numSame > maxSame ? numSame : maxSame)
            }
        }

        if ( maxSame < (lgth-2) ) {
            print a[i]
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
AATCAGTC
ACACCTGG
```

There may be ways to make the above more efficient, left as an exercise :-).